# How to trigger addClass only once?

Tags: jquery

Well guys, I think my code speaks for itself.

What I want is for the `chosen` class to be applied only to the first `.block-1 .options a` clicked and no other.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Ps. Obviously the jQuery code below doesn't work.

```
<div class="block-1">
<div class="options">
<a href="#">One</a>
</div>
<div class="options">
<a href="#">Two</a>
</div>
<div class="options">
<a href="#">Three</a>
</div>
</div>

$('.block-1 .options a').on('click', function(){
   $(this).one().addClass('chosen');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if any `a` tags have the `.chosen` class and if not apply the `.chosen` class to the clicked element:

```
$('.block-1 .options a').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.block-1 a.chosen').length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('chosen');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hidden field value to determine whether any link has been clicked yet:

```
 <input type=“hidden” id=“hField” />

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(“a”).on(“click”, function(){
        if ($(“#hField”).val() != “1”){
            $(“#hField”).val(“1”);
            $(this).addClass(“chosen”);
        }
     });
 });
```